# White space below image - display:block not working

Tags: css, css-float

My header got an image, and im trying to place a text block over the image in order to make a part of the image "clickable". However, when i do that, a white space below the header and above the body shows up.

Does anyone know how can i correct this? Img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIC9F.jpg

CSS

```
    .meio {
        background: url("http://www.oneideaperday.com/meio5.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position:50% 0%;
        text-indent: 250px;
           }

    .img {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
      vertical-align:bottom;
      position:relative; top:5px;
      text-align: center;
          }

     .image {
             position:relative;
             float:center;
         text-align: center
             }

     .image .text {
               opacity: 0;
                   position:absolute;
                   top:55px; 
                   left:505px;
                   width:300px; 
                   }

     .img .termos {
                   position:absolute;
                   top:55px; 
                   left:835px;
                   width:300px;
               -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
               -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
               font-size: 10px;
               opacity: 0;
                   }
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<body>
    <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.oneideaperday.com/header1.png" alt=""/>
        <div class ="termos">
            <p>Termos de Uso</p>
    </div>  

    <div class="meio">
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
    </div>


    <div class="image">
      <img alt="" src="http://www.oneideaperday.com/footer.png" />
      <div class="text">
        <p><a href="http://www.acumula.com.br">Acumula.com.br</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a closing `</div>` to your markup just before `<div class="meio">` and the whitespace gap went away for me. As @pebbl said, you have a lot of markup errors, and correcting that one seems to have fixed your immediate concern.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<body>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://www.oneideaperday.com/header1.png" alt=""/>
      <div class ="termos">
          <p>Termos de Uso</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="meio">
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
        a</br>
    </div>


    <div class="image">
      <img alt="" src="http://www.oneideaperday.com/footer.png" />
      <div class="text">
        <p><a href="http://www.acumula.com.br">Acumula.com.br</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</head>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have quite a few errors in your markup... I'd fix those first before trying to solve the problem - as it may go away automatically:

First off, make sure all your open and close elements tie up to one another *(as you can see from the image below, you don't have enough `</div>` employed... the body, head and html are all complaining about non matching tags)*. You'll need to add in a `</head>` and sorting out your indentation will help you track down the unclosed tags.

Secondly `</br>` isn't a tag, you should be using `<br />`

[image: Screenshot showing incorrect markup]

What happens if you try the markup below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://www.oneideaperday.com/header1.png" alt="" />
      <div class="termos">
        <p>Termos de Uso</p>
      </div>  
      <div class="meio">
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.oneideaperday.com/footer.png" />
        <div class="text">
          <p><a href="http://www.acumula.com.br">Acumula.com.br</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on the corrections pebbl, however the blank space persists: http://www.oneideaperday.com/base.html

Comment: No problem. Ok well now you've got the HTML sorted, you'll need to apply `display:block` to your image. Images automatically tend to have spacing arounding them when they are displayed inline (this changes across browsers) so it's always best to come up with a layout that allows you to use images with `display:block;`. It also seems I have set your divs incorrectly, jimp's answer looks like he's got the divs correct. But Jimp's markup still produces a thin white line for me.

Answer (score 1):

Close the `.termos` `div` and use the image as a `background-image` for `img`.